# compare date/time via VBA with date/time in Access DB

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, date, time

How to compare a date/time via VBA with a date/time in an Access DB?

The query I use

```
adoRS.Open "SELECT * FROM currentpositions WHERE ((currentpositions.
[dateLT])=" & "#" & date_from_message & "#" & ")", adoConn, adOpenStatic,
adLockOptimistic
```

I only achieve to compare a date.
Anybody an idea?

Regards
Camastanta

Comment: What format are your dates in?

Answer (score 3):

```
adoRS.Open "SELECT * FROM currentpositions WHERE DateValue(currentpositions.
[dateLT]) = DateValue(" & "#" & date_from_message & "#)", adoConn, adOpenStatic,
adLockOptimistic
```

See, if the above helps.
`DateValue` extracts the date part from a given date/time. So, it can be used to compare date, ignoring the time part.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you should never build your SQL statements using string concatenation.  Instead use [parameterized SQL queries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200190).  This will save you from problems like the one you are facing with date/time comparison.

Comment: I disagree. Using parameterized SQL queries is much harder to work with when you have to go back to maintain and test the code.

Comment: I would say it depends on where the value you're plugging into the string is coming from. If it's coming from a control the user can't type free text into, you're completely safe in Access. A text field with a date mask or that can only be edited with a date picker control will never be subject to SQL injection in any form.

Comment: @Tony: Why do you find it harder to maintain?
@David: I don't think it is just a matter of SQL injection. It also saves you from date formatting problems etc. Also, if your Access application is backed by a SQL Server, parameterized queries allow SQL Server to cache the query plans which gives you better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Does your system have dates in either yyyy-mm-dd or dd-mm-yyyy format?  If so see [Return Dates in US #mm/dd/yyyy# format](http://www.mvps.org/access/datetime/date0005.htm) to convert your dates in mm-dd-yyyy so Access can work with them properly.